Turning monochromatic light into polychromatic light using shutter?
Consider this. Due to Heisenberg‘s uncertainty principle, a particle that is localized in position space must be spread out in momentum space. In particular, this applies to photons, so a photon that is not spread out over the entire universe has no definite momentum.
This, as far as I understand, is the reason why atoms (who have discrete spectra) are actually able to absorb photons (the probability for two real numbers being exactly equal is zero).
Now imagine a narrow hole, together with a very fast shutter. If you were to shine monochromatic light on that shutter (e.g. a laser), and if you were to open that shutter for just a very brief moment, you would have light that is very localized in space. Thus, it would have to be very spread out in momentum space, i.e. it would be polychromatic.
Is that really possible? If so, has such an experiment ever been performed?

this is not true , in the mainstream standard model  " so a photon that is not spread out over the entire universe has no definite momentum." a photon is a point particle with an (x,y,z,t) four vector and an energy momentum four vector.. The HUP applies to the probability of measurement a particular (x,y,z,t) . It is not spread out as you imagine.

By position/momentum of the photon being spread out I of course mean the wave function being spread out in position/momentum space.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524012/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311663/123208 & links therein.

just estimate how fas your shutter has to be!

I should add that "monochromatic" means of a single frequency. A single frequency light is composed of single energy photons= h*nu

I voted to reopen this because I think it's perfectly mainstream. However, it may be a duplicate of one of the questions that PM 2Ring linked.

Why did this get closed? What the OP describes is what Q switching does and we can indeed relate the bandwidth to the pulse duration.

as pointed out by @annav, your first statement is incorrect. HUP refers to simultaneous measurements, whereas your argument is based on Fourier analysis and involves no measurements at all.   Basically the uncertainty of the HUP is different in nature from the finite localization effects Fourier analysis.

I don't get what point you are trying to make @ZeroTheHero. What's relevant here is that the wave function cannot be arbitrarily localized in momentum and position space. This "Fourier Uncertainty" is simply the special case of the operator version of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle when you take the operators to be position and momentum operators.
In any case, how is the first statement wrong? Are you claiming that a wave function can be arbitrarily localized both in position and momentum space?

my point is that your (pretty interesting) question is not related the HUP (at all).

So, your point is that the inequality relating the variance of a wave function and the variance of the Fourier transform of the wave function shouldn't be called "Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle", or do you mean something else? Or are you saying that this relationship is irrelevant to the question?

correct.  The Fourier stuff is independent of the quantum stuff.  They happens to look the same for position and momentum.  For instance there is a Fourier relation between time and frequency, but it makes no sense “quantumly” since time is not an observable in quantum mechanics.  The quantum equivalent of $\Delta E\Delta t$ is a very nuanced version of the Fourier one.

Irregardless of how you derive it, via Fourier analysis or via operator algebra, the inequality tying the standard deviations of position and momentum to each other certainly is both an instance of Heisenberg's Uncertainy Principle and relevant to this question.

It would be hard to do the experiment you describe using any form of mechanical shutter as the duration of the pulse has to be very short to significantly increase the bandwidth of the light. You'd need a pulse duration of around ten times the period or shorter to have a big effect, and since the frequency of light is of order $10^{14}$ to $10^{15}$ Hz you need a duration of well under a picosecond.
The closest I know of to your suggested experiment is Q switching in lasers although I don't think this can get much below a nanosecond. However it is still short enough to measurably affect the bandwidth.
It is possible, indeed routinely so, to generate very short laser pulses although whether this fits with your idea of the experiment you will have to decide. These ultrashort pulses do indeed have a greatly increased spread of frequencies.
We should note that although what you describe may seem strange to you it is a well know effect that has been understood for hundreds of years. Any signal can be Fourier transformed to calculate its frequency spectrum, and this applies to electromagnetic pulses just as it applies to any form of wave.

A short and sweet answer. I would have wrote the exact same.

Thanks! I just wanted to confirm my understanding, and your answer does precisely that. The effect, even though easy enough to predict and understand on the theoretical level, just seemed very surprising to me. I recognize that it may be very hard to realize in an experiment.

imo, your answer is fine as long as the laser is not monochromatic, but has a width in frequencies. Monochromatic means there is one color, which means one frequency which means a single frequency for the photons.
